# Can I avoid using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is actually not a technical question ! Im learning Javascript (I started a few months ago with AngularJs for a big school project) and am now focusing on plain Js, and Im still quite a noob but Im starting to get the 'abstract logic' of it and im having fun.
I 've often heard that jQuery was a bit 'hacky' and not always a clean way to achieve things, but it does work efficiently. My question is: can I keep it to 'good ol' Js forever or will I inevitably have some day to use jQuery for tricky things? Can I have your advises on that? Thanks !
(sorry if Im not in the good section?)

Comment: apparently you can avoid from using readable paragraphs

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely avoid it (unless you are using things that explicitly depend on it). A majority of the time most things that are commonly done with jQuery can be done fairly easily in pure Javascript. It really just depends on your particular applications and how much you want to invest in learning pure Javascript.

jQuery is ultimately just a more "user friendly" wrapper for Javascript, and as a result, isn't going to be as quick as running the plain JS on it's own.

Comment: You can do mant things with JS. JQuery is just one thing, which saves you a ton of time.  If you understand JS, JQ is not a problem. Can't imagine if working on modern webapps that JQ (or alternatives) is not part of it. Its just another lib.

Comment: JQuery is nothing more than a JavaScript library that someone else wrote to help make difficult tasks easier. But, JavaScript and CSS (and HTML) have come a long way since JQuery first came out and much of what people rely on JQuery doing for them is easily done without it these days.  Also, the statement that *"it does work efficiently"* is not actually correct as JQuery is just wrapper code around plain JavaScript and, often, it adds to the total time needed to run code.

Comment: @RonWilliams ok thanks ! For now I really feel like I want to keep it clean

Comment: @DevMoutarde, you have to compare the time it will save you, as the developer, when doing complex tasks compared to the performance impact it will have on your project. If it will take you 2x as long to create the code but adds less than 1 second of load time I would consider jQuery to be worth adding.    But no, jQuery is not needed its just a useful tool. I.E. you can do `$('')` to select a class/id or many of the other complex selectors where with JS you would need to write a condition to check which `document.getElement` you need to use

Comment: jQuery is not completely redundant, but I would concentrate on more integral frameworks like Angular, React, etc. if you are trying to sharpen your skills. jQuery is the technology of the past `;)`

Comment: I see... well I guess I ll make up my mind in a few years ahah for now Im just beginning so..

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 ahah yeah thats pretty much what I had in mind

Comment: @ScottMarcus One of its biggest advantages and "difficult tasks" it makes easier is cross-browser and legacy browser support. It has all of the quirks and polyfills built right in - people seriously undervalue that. But yes, jQuery is not a panacea by any means and should be used only where appropriate.

Comment: If you find yourself doing the same sets of things over and over, if you have any sense, you will organize these things into a set of functions -- using a existing library like jQuery (or the others) saves you the trouble of writing and debugging those functions (on browsers of varying standards compliance!)  Yes, encapsulating stuff adds overhead, but that rarely matters today (and premature optimization is a far greater sin).  Write clearly and quickly, don't reinvent a broken wheel.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 That is absolutely not true. jQuery usage in the latest frameworks is fewer and farther between, but it definitely still has its place in most enterprise applications

Comment: @mhodges Agreed. But, many of the great features that made it so widely adopted are no longer needed since they are now standardized in HTML, CSS and JS.

Comment: @mhodges What about my statement is not true? jQuery *is* the technology of the past, but you are right, it is still more or less widely used. But would you consider it for a new enterprise project? I would not suggest to learn jQuery right now; you can still easily learn it if your actually on a jQuery project.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Most definitely - `document.querySelector` is 100% thanks to jQuery. However, even basic things like function chaining, add/remove/has class, performing the same operation on a collection of DOM elements, etc. are still cumbersome with vanilla JS.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 React, angular, meteor, etc. are certainly badass technologies, but are not the end-all-be-all of front end frameworks. However, even if they were, jQuery still has a place. Would I write an entire enterprise application today using ONLY jQuery? Absolutely not. But to say it is not worth learning is too far, imo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question might be better suited for r/webdev.

But yes you can avoid using jQuery altogether. jQuery is great for DOM manipulation. It has a stigma for turning large projects with a lot of jQuery into 'spaghetti code' but it is still widely used. That being said, whatever you can do in jQuery can be done in different ways using JS, CSS or HTML.